# Extract data from a specific cell in a table using BeautifulSoup?

Tags: python, parsing, beautifulsoup

I'm trying to extract the triage waiting times for a specific hospital to feed into other applications. Data from ALL local hospitals is available from: https://www.health.wa.gov.au/emergencyactivity/EDdata/edsv/

Here is the progress I have made so far:

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

URL = 'https://www.health.wa.gov.au/emergencyactivity/EDdata/edsv/'

headers = {
    "User-Agent": 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:76.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/76.0'
}

page = requests.get(URL, headers=headers)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

table_rows = soup.find_all('tr')

for tr in table_rows:
    td = tr.find_all('td')
    row = [i.text for i in td]
    print(row)
```

I want to extract only the triage time for Sir Charles Gairdner Hospital but have no clue how to do that. Any help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are almost there. Try something like this:

```
from bs4 import Tag

table_rows = soup.select('tr td')
for tr in table_rows:
    if tr.text ==  'Sir Charles Gairdner Hospital':
            for ns in tr.next_siblings:            
                if isinstance(ns,Tag):
                    print(ns.text)
```

Another alternative:

```
table = soup.select('table')[0]
for row in table:
        if isinstance(row,Tag):
            tds = row.select('td')
            if len(tds)>0 and tds[0].text=='Sir Charles Gairdner Hospital':
                    for td in tds: 
                        print(td.text)
```

Output:

```
73
5
36
```

Edit:
To print just the triage waiting time for that location, use:

```
for tr in table_rows:
    if tr.text ==  'Sir Charles Gairdner Hospital':
            print(tr.next_sibling.text) #note: it's "next_sibling", not "siblings" this time
```

Comment: Amazing! Is there a way to only scrape information from only the first column (i.e. the triage waiting time)?

Comment: @VrajBarot Do you mean the whole column for all hospitals or just for Gairdner?

Comment: Just Gairdner. We're trying to design a waiting sign in the ED for the hospital, so all other data is no needed. I essentially just need the waiting time number for Gairdner.

Comment: You're a hero! I only just stated learning python last week for this project, so needless to say you have been an absolute god send! Thanks a bunch.